# What is the difference between size function usage in numpy (Python) np.size(a1) and a1.size()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

i have an array a1 in numpy .when using the size function i have encountered two ways both are giving correct answer, but i dint understand the difference.

below is the code used:

```
import numpy as np

a1= np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

print(a1.size)

print(np.size(a1))
```

out put is : 6

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. `a.size` is a method call that executes `np.prod(a.shape)`.  While `np.size(a)` returns `a.size`.

[Link to Method Docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.size.html#numpy.ndarray.size)
[Link to `np.size` Code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/44d3b5976d55d028e85c075933837dff150d9840/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L2739-L2748)